# How to override the system onbackpress() in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Problem:

In my compose page -> I have list of elements, if I press anyone I will show sub contents in same page (hide the main content and show the sub content)

If I press back button from topbar, I handle myself by own logic.

**But I can't able to handle system back press.**

**Question :**

Is there any way to override the onBackPressed() in Jetpack Compose?

My code:

```
 @Composable
private fun AnimationRootView() {

 //Main content list
 Column(){

 }

 //Sub content list
 Column(){

 if(detail1Clicked)
   Detail1()
if(detail2Clicked)
   Detail2()
 }
 ....
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can use [`BackHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#backhandler):

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    BackHandler {
        // your action
    }
}
```

To get the same effect as with `super.onBackPressed()` call, the most compose way it to use `enabled` parameter depending on your state:

```
BackHandler(
    // your condition to enable handler
    enabled = isOverlayPresented
) {
    // your action to be called if back handler is enabled
    isOverlayPresented = false
}
```

If you need to both handle back press and perform default back action, you can use `LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner`. Since `BackHandler` is also using it under the hood, you need to wait next recomposition to make sure your back handler is disabled, then you can perform `onBackPressed`:

```
val onBackPressedDispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current?.onBackPressedDispatcher
var backPressHandled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
BackHandler(enabled = !backPressHandled) {
    println("back pressed")
    backPressHandled = true
    coroutineScope.launch {
        awaitFrame()
        onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()
        backPressHandled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the alternative for `super.onBackPressed()` to trigger the usual back press behaviour if I want to close the screen after the second back-press?

Comment: @SpiralDev You can pass `BackHandler(enabled = enabled)` parameter, which you can determine depending on your state.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to react using a `ComposeView` any ideas?

Comment: @desgraci please create a separate question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SpiralDev I guess we can use navController.popBackStack() as a replacement for super.onBackPressed()

Comment: @TalhaAkbar by doing so you're guessing what action should be done, it may be correct to pop in some cases, but not in all of them - e.g. the view is topmost and you need to close the app. as as said the the second commend, you should pass `enabled = false` in case when you don't need to handle it - `enabled` parameter can be dynamically calculated with a mutable state variable

Comment: @PhilDukhov But sometimes its much easier if it'd accept a return value of Boolean - when true, back was handled, not handled and it should perform the default action.

Comment: @MihaMarkic I agree that it may be easier, but we don't have choice here - `BackHandler` is just a wrapper around "new" system API, `OnBackPressedDispatcher`

Comment: @PhilDukhov Have you encountered a case where the BackHandler won't work if you background and then foreground the app?

Comment: @Prudhvi no. I suggest you debugging it starting with `Activity.onBackPressed`

Comment: Is it possible to execute custom behavior + trigger the usual back press behaviour with one back click?

Comment: @rjhcnf I'm looking into the same and so far it looks like you'd need to get an instance of the OnBackPressedDispatcher 
 from the owner (either from LocalLifecycleOwner, Activity, Dialog, Fragment) and call `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: @tricknology thanks for the idea, and check out updated answer

Comment: THIS IS A CRUTCH! You should not call  `onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()` inside `BackHandler`

Comment: @TalhaAkbar no, you can't use `navController.popBackStack() as a replacement for super.onBackPressed()`, it has nothing to do with Activity back stack

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack Compose, you can use BackHandler to execute custom behavior when a user clicks the back button. The problem is that you can’t directly cause a normal back press action in the same click event. A solution is to coordinate these two actions within your custom behavior. To do this, you would need to perform your action first and then trigger the default back behavior with other navigation methods like navController.

The BackHandler doesn’t provide an interface for standard back button functions, but it does provide ways for users to implement their own actions.

```
BackHandler {
    // Do stuff..
    navController.popBackStack()
}
```

Comment: What is navController?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

Comment: don't do it... `navController.popBackStack()` - if you call it on top level composable screen then it will just stay freeze with the latest frame of your composable screen, you can't exit activity (back pressed behavior) with `navController.popBackStack()`. The NavController only controls its own back stack (i.e., the destinations you've put on the back stack) and does not contain or operate on the activity back stack.