# On Back Pressed Finish the Activity in JetPack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have Two Two Activities Login And Main In Main I have 6 to 7 Compose Screens in them DashBoard in the one of the screen in Main Activity I want to finish my Activity when I click onBack on from only DashBoard Screen not from remaining screens .I used Some methods it's again opining dashboard when i pressed On Back. I am net to Jectpack compose so which method i have to follow to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the system onbackpress() in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69151521/how-to-override-the-system-onbackpress-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BackHandler` composable function in your dashboard screen.

first make Extension's function of Activity's context

```
fun Context.getActivity(): AppCompatActivity? = when (this) {
    is AppCompatActivity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.getActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

Now use this in your `composable` function like this

```
val context = LocalContext.current.getActivity()!!

 BackHandler() {
        context.finish()
    }
```

This will finish the activity from `Dashboard screen`.

Comment: it's not working I am not getting finish() through with context object which class object is used for context

Comment: Thanks but still not working I am using I using ComponentActivity and I replaced  AppCompatActivity  with ComponentActivity still when i back pressed it's going to login activity instead of close the app

Answer (score 0):

Add the extension function to your app.

```
/**
 * Find a [androidx.activity.ComponentActivity] from the current context.
 * By default Jetpack Compose project uses ComponentActivity for MainActivity,
 * It is a parent of [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity] or [AppCompatActivity]
 */
fun Context.findActivity(): ComponentActivity? = when (this) {
    is ComponentActivity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

I try to find a `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity` activity, this is important because `AppCompatActivity` is sometimes not used in Jetpack Compose project. `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity` is safer because it is super class of `AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity`.

In your `@Composable` Dashboard Screen function. You should use `BackHandler` to listen for back press event from the system, if you already have a back button in your screen just call `context.findActivity()?.finish()` inside `onClick` of the button

```
fun BookScreen(
    //...
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    BackHandler {
        context.findActivity()?.finish()
    }
    // your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use popstackback instead of navigate

Comment: this answer would be improved by explaining why.