Flutter Back button should navigate to Home Page
After checking various pages and ChatGPT, I need to ask for help here. I want to have a logic that once I am logged into the app and navigate through the pages, the back button should always navigate back to the home page. I am not talking about the leading back button, that one is disabled. It is the behavior when the use is using the device back button.
On the home page I have disables the back button with:

return PopScope(
canPop: false

Now on the other pages like the profile, I want the back button to navigate to the home page. Do I need PopScope for it and if so how can I do it? I tried it, but failed hard on that :D The Flutter dev documentation didn't help either. :(

Updated answer (see comments below):
The widget BackButtonListener can be used to register a callback that is executed when the device back button is pressed:
class CustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackButtonListener(
      onBackButtonPressed: () async {
        // Use the app navigator to navigate to the desired page. 
        // GoRouter.of(context).go('/');
        return true;
      },
      child: ...
    );
  }
}

Note: To use BackButtonListener, there must be an ancestor Router widget in the tree (see docs).
One example is the MaterialApp.router widget:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of the application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'App with customized back button',
      routerConfig: routerConfig, // Add your router configuration here. 
    );
  }
}

For reference, the router configuration is an object of type RouterConfig.
Example with go_router:
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final routerConfig = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
     GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home Page',
      builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
    ),
     GoRoute(
      path: '/custom-page',
      name: 'Custom Page',
      builder: (context, state) => const CustomPage(),
    ),
  ], 
);


Old answer (shows how to customize the AppBar back button):
You could specify a custom leading widget for your AppBar if the user is logged in.
In the example below,  the leading widget is an IconButton with an onPressed callback that takes care of the navigation.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class CustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: isLoggedIn ? IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).go('/')) : null, // Navigate                  
         title: const Text('CustomPage'),                          //  to home            
      ),
      body: ... , 
      ), 
    );
  }
}


Thank you for your response. I forgot to mention, that I dont have a leading back button on the app bar. I have disabled it. I want that if the user ist on the profile and clicks on the device back button then the app should navigate to the home page. So it is about the device back button and not the app bar back button.

Can you use the BackHandler as described here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69151521/how-to-override-the-system-onbackpress-in-jetpack-compose

@rod-san, it would be good to mention that you meant the device back button in the question title and body. I see someone already posted another answer related to the app bar back button.

Yeah I totally forgot it. I just edited it.

@rod-san, updated the answer.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(contex).push(
MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext _) => YourPage(),
),),              
         title: const Text('YourPage'),                            
      ),
      body: .......... , 
      ), 
    );
  }
}

Without using third party libraries. Try it with MaterialPageRoute

Thank you for your response! I just edited the text. I have disabled the leading back button. I want to have the behavior described above for the device back button when that one is used.

I suppose the home page is your first page when the user logs in and opens the app again. If not, you should be using named routes for better control. Assuming that's already set up, here’s a clean way to handle this.
We’ll use the WillPopScope widget (deprecated but still works for your use case). This widget lets us intercept the back gesture or back button press and handle it manually. When the user triggers a back action, we’ll pop all the pages until the home page.
class NestedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // Navigate back to the home page by clearing the stack
        Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
        return false; // Prevent default back behavior
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Nested Page')),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('This is a nested page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here, WillPopScope widget will captures the back gesture or button press, allowing us to override it with custom logic. In this case, we use Navigator.popUntil to clear all pages above the first one (home page) and ensure the user lands back at home. The return false statement prevents the default back behavior from occurring.
If you’re using named routes, you can modify the navigation like this:
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  '/', // Name of the home route
  (route) => false, // Remove all other routes from the stack
);

Hope this answers your question mate.
